# Convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(1-2^{-n})z^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I've been working with the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(1-2^{-n})z^n$ for the last few hours and I'm starting to get a little lost in trying to figure out a few things for an exercise.

First of all, I've managed to find the radius of convergence ofr the series with relative ease using $R=lim\frac{\vert a_n\vert}{\vert a_{n+1}\vert}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Now the radius of convergence is 1 here and I' asked about whether or not the sum converges *at* $\vert z\vert=R$. I'm a little confused here as I don't really know how much I can say about it considering this is on the boundary of the convergence. I considered saying something about Abel's Theorem, but as far as I understand the theorem only says something *if* the series is indeed convergent. Besides when I set $z=1$ the series becomes:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n-\frac{n}{2^n}$

The second term grows smaller and the first grows larger, suggesting the whole expression grows larger. This must mean that the series diverges here, right?

Secondly I'm asked to show that the sum function for the power series can be written as:

$F(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{2x}{(2-x)^2}$

I'm assuming this has something to do with the convergence of the series, but I'm not really able to see how to show this.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> This must mean that the series diverges

As you have written it, it only means that the series diverges at $z=1$. You want to show that the series diverges whenever $|z|=1$. But you can use the same argument.

For the second part, rewrite $\sum n(1-2^{-n})z^n$ as $\sum nz^n-\sum n\left(\dfrac{z}{2}\right)^n$. So now you just have to evaluate $\sum nw^n$ at $w=z$ and $w=z/2$. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yeah I see it now. Thanks a bunch! Do you have any advice for the second part? It's got me completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

If $b_n=a_n z^n$, then we have for $|z|=1$ that

$$|b_n|=|a_n|=n-n\frac{1}{2^n} \to \infty$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Conclusion ?